# @ symbol unrecognized

Tags: unit-test

Below code creates error on save: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: @ at line 15 column 0

Why is @ an unexpected symbol?  @istest or @isTest is all over the Salesforce docs, I have tried both:

```
public class SimpleClass {

 public void foo() {
   System.debug('foo here');
 }





}



@istest
public class SimpleClassTestClass {

    @istest
    public static void Test(){

    System.debug('test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first @istest is coming after the closing tag ('}') of your class. Actually anything put there will result in an error.

You either have to put your tests in a separate class, or include them inside the SimpleClass definition. That last option is not allowed after Summer '13 (API version 28.0). So best practice is to create a separate test class.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put two different classes in single one. You can have only single parent class in Apex so move your test class as separate class or if you want to put that in same class change your class api version to 27.0 with following code **(though it is not recommended to use any deprecated functionality)**

```
public class SimpleClass {

 public void foo() {
   System.debug('foo here');
 }


  @isTest static void testMethodName(){

    System.debug('test');
  }


}
```

Read more about isTest from [**Salesforce documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm)

Comment: I'm tempted to down-vote for recommending using a lower API Version. They deprecated that functionality for a reason. Separation Of Concerns is clearly preferable for this scenario.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I also don't support any deprecated functionality because there is always a reason to deprecate any functionality but it all depends on user "IF" he thinks it is feasible for him they can go for that option.

Comment: K, you just made it seem like the primary option in your initial post. I figured you didn't treat it as such, that's why i held off on the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting both outer classes in the same class, you'll want to create a second class and have them be very separate:

```
public class SimpleClass {

 public void foo() {
   System.debug('foo here');
 }

}
```

then a totally separate class for:

```
@istest
private class SimpleClassTestClass {

    @istest
    public static void Test(){

    System.debug('test');
    }
}
```